# Powered by (Imgur)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader, imgur

Imgur logo is not visible on some sites when image upload dialog is open. E.g. here on MSE is visible:

> [image: mse]

But not visible on SO:

> [image: so]

Comment: I'm going to [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) for this. Do you see the black imgur logo in [this image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/img-upload.svg?v=16d9e4614ece)?

Comment: @balpha [nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mXoC.png)

Comment: Definitely caching then. Some proxy between your browser and our CDN (inclusively, on both ends) caching the old version of the image even though the cache breaker has changed. Does clearing your browser cache help? If not, does [this image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/img-upload.svg?v=16d9e4614ecex) (just appended an "x" to the cache breaker) have the logo?

Comment: @balpha clearing cache doesn't help, but I see [a logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk28d.png) on your last link.

Comment: We've purged the CDN cache, can you try again?

Comment: @balpha looks fixed, i.e. visible now!

Comment: Great, thanks for the heads-up!